# Lualatex rendering of Zalgo text

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode, accents

There are many question about rendering unicode in latex that are subject to interpretation, I would like to ask how to properly render Zalgo text with lualatex (or any other tex; just to specify a focus), that is i want to have this:

T̸̙̖͕͕̣̥͕̙̓̋ͯ̇ͨ̎́̀̚o͎̤͍̠̯̣̦̖̔̈́̚͝ ̗̭͚̲̮͎̝͓ͨͫ̿̍̔͟͠i̳̙̪̙͎̗̠͌͐̃͛̈́ͅn̥͚͇̪̽̅̈́͌͌̀͞v̴͎͖̝̝̯̦̣̪ͩͧ̓ͥ̽̔̎͑͒o͙ͦͭ̀͝k̗̯̥̅̏̈́͑ͪ̋͞e͛ͩ҉̨҉̖͚̙ ̴͕̰̮̲̤͎̬̼ͥ̽̽ͬ̆͆͟t͕̳͈͖̪͍̞̭̐̊ͯͯͩ̇̊́h̰̅ͤ͒̂̄́e̵̯͙̓̾͑̀́ ̢̻͍̣̟͈̍̽͆̑̆ḥ̠̞̺̯ͥ̽̉ͥ̊̃ͨì̡̼̯̹̭̙͉̪̰̄ͤ́v̤̦ͦ̅̽̚͡ͅe̦̯̙̲̪̐̄̅͛ͫ̀̄̇͟͢-̡̘̭̓ͪ͒̄̽m̵̲̺͔̩̅̅̉̓͌̌ị̲̣̮̦͕̝͇̂̉̌ͩ̒̎̊͞n̰̮̦̪͈̩̄͐ͬ̋̈́͂̕͠ͅdͮͧ̊̐͜͏̮̪̰ ̡͚͇͈̙͕̣̲͇ͯͣr̖̎̾͜͝e͑̊̎̈ͧ͌҉̤̫̥p̃̓́͂̈́̈҉̠̻̙̞͓̮̮̙̪r̴̦̭̺̝̤̪̪̗͒ͦͨ͊̆̎̚͘e̶̬͕͗ͭs͍͓̩͊̊̇̾ͬê͏̴̯̩͈̟̮͈̥ͅn͚̜̗͈̫̠̖̗͆͛͡ţ̠̳̩̻̭̿̊̒ͣ͘͢i͚̺̬̳͛̏̉͆ͣ͋̀͞ͅņ̝ͮ̄̕͟ǵ̡̟͈͉̭ͮ̈́̔̆ͣͬ̚͟ ̮̱̯ͮ̌̔̓̈̂ͪͯ̀c̵̵̶͇̙̟͚̪̤͍͖̖̄̃͒͐̃̊ȟ̬̬̦̲̖͙̫̔ͮ̍́a̒̍ͣ̑͂ͭ͏͙̖o̢̖͔̞̫̩͚̗̝ͬ̍̌ͧ͆ͨͨ́s̾ͩ̀̅͐͗ͧͭ͏̜͍͈͓̲̞̦̥.̳̥̱̋̃̊̅̕͘
̸̢͕̽͗̀ͣ̄̎͆ͨ͞I̢̟̪͎͔̜̥̙̥̬͛ͤͯ͐ǹ̀҉͎͎̜v̷̦̼̙̱̍̋̚o̵̢̪̥͐͛k̸̺͙̲͌́ͅi̛̞̹̹̞̤̭ͬ͛̾̍͑ͥ̑̕͜n̡͖͋͂̿́̕͞ǵͤ͂ͤ̇҉̜͔̱͓̮̜ ̵̴̼̞̟̬͒̽̈́̔̍̎͋̈͗t̡̺͔͚̖̼̺̞̍̔̔̈́̽͟͝h̲́̈̏̃̋͢ę̹̭ͦ̽ͤͭͦͅ ̪͔̜̞̺͓ͤͯͤ́͢͝f͓̮͕͇̼͆ͧ̈́̓͝e̛͍̮͙̼̰͍̜̜̾̂ͭ̀̅͋̈́̓̕e̢̩̫͆͊͟l̵̢̟̥̥̰͓̪̖ͮ̔͋ỉͧ̿̒̿ͩ҉̼͕̫͈n̗͔̩̗͖̳͍̺̱͗̇͗̏͑ͦ̐g̶̥͍̺̰͉͇̘̈ͫ͑̀͡ ̧̹̳̬͇͓̮̜͉͌̊̆͐̈́͊o̩͖̖ͧͩ̔̓̏̇ͨ͒ͩ͘͘f͎̺ͪͨ͊͆͗͒̇ͮ͡ ̨̼̘̭͓̪̉͌̒͒̔͐ͨͅc͕̼͕͂́ḫ̶̮̹̖͙̋̄̑̆̇̉͜͝a̷͕̻̩͉̘͎͑͋̒̕ȏ̢͙͚ͬ͂̿ͭ̎̋̄s̡̍ͫ͐̓̽̀ͨͬ̕҉̹̬̳͉͓̗͔͉̫.̟̙̯̍̈͒ͯ͝
̠̻̓ͦͪ̀W͙͆̍ͮ̂͆̀̚i̓̄ͦ̋͟͞҉̩͉͚̖t͛̍̾͒ͨͦ̅҉͉̼́h͖͈̲͈̟͚͗̂͋ͤ́͢ ̙͚̙̄͊͝ͅǫ̷̲̖̖̘͋́̈́ù͉̫͔͓͇̇̌͒͒̈ͪ͜t̴̪̀̓ͦ̾̿͘͜ ̰̹͙ͤ͢o̝̝̬̮̥̟̳̍̀̋̇̑ͭͅr̯̟̝̠͍͇̭̤͚ͨͯ̿ͬ̔ͤd̵̘̮͎̖̯͇ͪ̀̐͠e̲̭̲̺̥͍̰͎͆ͫr̡̛̭ͣͦ̋̕.̫͓̯͎ͧ̐̌͑̕͠
̧̢͚̩̪̦̮̏̍̇ͮ̒T̴̼̼̮̝̉ͬ̍ͤͥ̃̍͡h̴̠̣̙͎͋͐̀̚͠e̛͒͌̍̈́͐͑̆̿͌͏̰̦͖̻̱ ̴̛͈͚͔̊ͨ̀ͩ͝Ņ̸̥͎̄ͧ̚͞e̺͚͈͖̠̘̤̽ͬ̎ͧ́ͭ̚͞z̼̫͓̺̹̮̝̮͗̚͡p̧̨̪̘͛̾̂̿̿ͫͦ̍ę̴͔͓̥̦͔͚̬̔ͧ͌͌ͨ̈́̊ͧͧr̾̈́ͥ͐̄̒̋͐҉̝̮͓̜̕d̷͕͈̥̦̺͔̳̊i̶͙͎̯̜̦̻͊̿̏ͩ͛ã̦̾̓͒̉̚͠ͅn̬̘͙͓̣̓̐̓̈̽̈͐̿ͅ ̷͈̣̲̻̍͒ͣ̉ͩ̔ͩ͘h̾͌͐͏̴͔̫̲̤͙͚̣͉͇ị̳͓͙͖̟̊ͩ́̀v̛͈̜́͗̒̊ͣ̒̋ͬ͟͠ȩ̻̲̺͚̪̹̔̑̇͗ͮͭ̀͝ͅ-̸͎͔̮͈͙̻̝̳̎̈́ͬ͋͋̏̒ͯ̉͢m̳̈̾͋̑ͭ̑̆ͬị̷͕̯ͤ̀͝͡n̯̲͓͂ͪͨ̀ͧ͑͠d̦̤̗̲͈̖̗̹̔ͅ ̨̪̗̣̝͎̺͛͛ͬ̿́̾̅͞o̘̣͇̜̗̞̱͍̓ͅf̲̗̳̟̣́͊͞ ̛͚͙͇̞̱̠ͧͫ̋ͨ͌͌̈́ͭċ̴̨͈͑ͤͣ̐̂͞h͙̃͐ͧ̿͆̂̈̅a͙̲͇͎͈̋̌͐̾ǒ̴̫̯̭̖͎̄̉̈́͛̄́s̗͍͈͙͕̺̲͍̋ͮ͟.̢͙ͭͭͫ͆͞ ͓̼̹ͬͨ͆͂̽̅ͯ͝Ż̸̴̲̯̤̟͈̘̈́̏ͭ͐̓͑̒̀à́͒ͅl̴̛͈̋͌͊̕g͕̤̖̮̾ͪ̏̊͐̎ͦ͘o̧̙̥̤̣ͮ̑̍̆̿̓.̢̙̠͗͌͋͝ͅ ̩̩̲̘͕̣̥͙ͦ̓̄͌ͯ̉̌̉͝͠
̻̤̰͇̪̈͌͆̽̏ͣ̂̿͟͡H̺̽͌̈́ͣ͌̄e̗̜̜͒͋̂ͮ̉̑̈́̀̚͠ ̻̼͍͎ͧ̈́͝͠w̸̮̺̟̬̎ͫ̄̈́ͤ͂̌ͬ̓͝h̷͈̯̬̪̿̆̈͌͌̊̔̀̚o͆̈́̀ͩ͞͠͏̻̟̜̱̙ ̴̹̻̪̯̭̦͕͉̌̆̽͘W̧̧͔̺̦̯̙͕̾̒ͤ̑̇͞a̡̪̣̺̐͗̅ͩ̋̈́ͦͨ͢ȉ̉͞҉̢̝͉̻̩̹̰̤t̵̛̬̺͖̳̗͉̝̭͍̾̑̿́ͬͪ̂ͤs̴̫̱ͭͫ̆ͨ̈́ ̮͖̲̠̘̩̍̿́̚͡B̢͍̮̬̱̤̫̃ͬ̕ę̣̣̹̑͐̉ͪ̒ͧͅh̶͓̼̘ͭͨͯ̑̅͜ȋ̯͖̦́ͯͣ̿̒̐nͮͣͪͣ̏҉̹̮̩̭d͍̤̦̱͓̹̲͚̄̾̄̏͑̕ͅ ̠̤̿̿̉̍ͫT̾ͯ͏͏̡̣̼͚ͅh̶̹̠͈̗̋ͭͤͅe̘̫͍̮̥ͣͣ̐̂͐ͭ́ ̸͔̲͈̩̟̖̗͖̈̐͞ͅW̴̫̘̺̤̝͈̜̙ͤ̅̔ͩ̈́̑̊a̟̲͖ͤ̈́̂ͦͧͫl̷̥̺̙͎̝̬ͪͦͨ̐̔ͭ̓͐͞l̷̶̟̜̤̤̯̞̦̋ͬ̚.̸̵̜̩̄ͧͪͦ
̑̒͑̋͏̵̼͎̺̼ͅͅZ̡̘̤̮͇̞̪͉̞͐̏ͬͤͭͤͧ̀́Ḁ̪͖͚̫̼͔̼̆̐ͧ̓ͥ̓̓͝L̷͖͈ͪ͂̔̏̆̓̚͜Ģ̵̶̩̔̒ͦ̂̑͋̈́ͅO͊ͯ҉̟̮͇͔̬͉̣͡͡ͅ!̫̭̈́̅̌ͪ̃ͩ̚

in a pdf.

Just copypasting it inside a document does not work. Two possible kind of solution i can imagine would be:

1. an environment or a package that allow complex composing characters
2. or a way to input a text codepoint by codepoint

In this context i don't care whether symbols like emoticon or flags would work; just really weird looking text.

Comment: I assume you mean text as for example generated  by http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle exactly, I tried to describe it but since i am no unicode expert maybe that link is actually clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently loading a unicode capable font manually works

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
    Path           = ../fonts/,
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX
]{Symbola_hint}
\begin{document}

T̾̇̀ͮ͆ͣ͂ͫ̊҉̧̘̣̲̥̱͡o̸̷͔̮̹̮̦͈̜̊̊̆̐̂ ̷̘͓͉̽̓̓͒̚i͊͏̛̜̠̱̩͕ͅn̢̗̘͐̾͑̃͟v̠̪̥̮̰̘ͦͦ͒͌ͪ͒́͢ǫ̳͂̎̒͑̏̍ͭ̚͘͝k̞͈̫̥̳̲̫̲͈ͣͫ̂̐̑̅̐͐
e̍͌ͭ́̐̿͏̵̤̳ ̮̝̪͓̳̼̺̰̏͊́̀̌̓t̘̪ͬ̓͗̿͛̐ͨ̒ḧ̲͎̬̀e̵̪͇͚̪̘̋̿͜ ̶͗̏̔̑͒̚҉̩̞͓̭̠h̼̼͓̹̥̦ͥ̈̉ͬͭ̀̿̈́i̗̠͉̬̩̮̫̓̎̑ͣ̔͋͒͜v͕̱̮̜̭͖͔̞̂ͯ̇́ͤ́ë̴̸̞͎̱̪̂̋̎̋̆̚-̸̥̖̹̊͛m̖̬̟̰͎͂͋̀i̢̢̺̰͉͎̳ͨ̂̈́̕ͅn̙͔̩ͬ͛
d̵̘̤͈͖̬̖͔ͦͧ͛ͪ ̏͆̔ͯ͊ͭ҉̩̞̤̼̖̫̱͢ŗ͈̭̻̮̣̟̜ͯ̐̍̾e̟̠̙͕̭͂͢p̳͒̊ͅr̝̘̻̠̝̳̭͈̄͐́e̵̠͓͍̺͍̍̎̎ş͓͎̖͕͐͗ͩe̟̲̝̬͋̄ͮ̔́̀n̴̡̲̣͙̳̟ͧ̿̊́ͣ͂t̵̉̈͌ͨ͗͆ͣ͏͕̪̭͕́ͅͅi̢̙͙̭͎̔̔̐̂͂̇ͧ̾n͒̍͠͏͖̜͇͍͉̭̫ͅg̸͙̲̪͂ͤ̋̚̕͡ ̸̩̳̲͕̘̬͈̝̔̍̍ͥ̔ͪ̉̋͞c̰͕͍̏ͫͯ̾̓͌͠h̢̗̰̫̳̣͈͎̗̝ͨ̀̋̽́a̡̼̝͓͒ͣͯō̸̖̱̯͎̯̰͚ͥ̋͛̀̎̂͠͞s̢̯͓͌̒̓͆̎͊̆͌͘͜.̴̷̗̙͔̭̬̦̲͚͇͐̾́̋
    ͊̄ͭͪͥ҉̙̙͠T̪̹͚̦̣͕͇ͨ̊̀̍̔ͬ͢   h̷͉͙̪̻̻͈̬̠ͣ̓ͯ͜e̵͇͓͎̰̅͜ ͋̐ͪ͏̮͕͉̣̻͈̠̲N͓̼͚ͣe̴̙̙͖̓͂̂ͨz̶̺͙̥̳̮̫̹͋ͯp̞͉̠̙ͬ̾͑̃͑́ͯ̇͘͢͞ͅe̴͚̭̼̍̔͜r̬̹̣̻̣͛̂̉ͯ̔ḍ̳̻͙̺͔̹ͮͩ̑́͘iͦͧͯ̈͂ͧ̔̚҉͇
    ą͍̪̯̭̤̰̔̌̈́͠͞ͅn̵̢̫͍̒ͣ̀ͫ͑̇̂̋̚͘ ̲̘͕̼̭͙ͨ͗̌̌ͮͥ́̕͘h̤̺ͨ́ͯ͂̒ͯ̾̈́͝i̛̛̗̭̙ͫ̒̆̈ͭ̑̀̉v̷̯̹̻͇̳̙̉ͫ͊ͥe̱͇̜̪͋̂̾ͭͫ̌͑̾͢͠-̝̻̩͖͖̫̥̄̓̅̀͘͢m̘̱̔̑ͧ̇͟į͎ͪ̎̅͊͋͟ͅn̾̉̃̊̿̓ͫ̏͏̯̘͔͕͓d͓̝̊ͥ̓͋̊̒̕͞
     ̆́҉͈o̺̣̹̬͚̓̈̔͊͛͋̇̾f̨͚͔̥̺̻̝͍̫̏ͨ̾̅ ̥̲̣͙̌͂ͬ̂́ͮ͂ͅç̷̸̹̣̦̏͒͂̅͋͌̀̏̅ḥ̻̹͇͓͉̓ͩ̀͘͞à̰͍͑͐͟͠o̟̘̮͇̙̮̼̰̲̾ͦͥ͞sͦ̑͘҉͏̰̖̟ͅ.̺̬̟̲͉͖͈ͧ͊ ̷̎̊҉҉̠Ẕ̨͉͖̠͓͇̮̗ͤ̃ả̫̫̞͈̥͕͇̑̐͡ͅl̲̋ͨ͘͞g̵̨̙̗ͥ͊͐̊͌̽͂õͭͮ҉̯̲͇̲͉̟̼̹͢͢.̷̨̹͕̰̱̣̻͔̭̂̾͋͆̄́  ̰̭̻̘ͨ͊͆ͭ̀̈̈́͞ͅe̵͍̟̮̝̘͔̮͉̫͋̒͟͡ ͖̞̥̘͍̥́̂̒̽ͮ̎ͮͮͮ͜ẅ͑҉̶͙́h̲̣͔̻̼͔ͤͨ̉́͌̋̉̕o̴͙̦͗ͬ ̶̶̮͈̮͉̝̆͗ͤ͗́͡Ẉ̩̳͕͌̄̋ͧ̚͡ä̵̼͙̘̬̭̹͎͉͍̇ͣĩ̔̽̓ͭͫ́̄͏̛͇̖̪̠̮̪t͈͎̐̓̏͌̾̒̉s̛͇͈̝̫̱̮̠̻ͯ́ ̞ͭ͋́̊̉̿́B̼̞͚͂̃̃͘e̱̯͉̿̏̍ͪ̌ͧͭͮ͘h̢͕̪̓ͤͅi̸̛͙̰̗̦̟̼̤͆̀ͭͅṇ̸̂̑̅̾͡͡d̘̙͎͓̙͇͕̗̒ͫ͆̇̋̿͛ ̐̑̑

\end{document}
```