# "Glitch" text font

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know of a "glitch text" font available in LaTeX? I'm not even sure this is what this type of writing is technically called, but it's used on twitter by accounts like @glitchr_. Here's an example of some text, as generated from https://lingojam.com/GlitchTextGenerator (apologies for obscuring some of the question text):

T̷̝̗̰̞̙̞̖̱̥̯̙̖̯̲̜̜͙̪̀̑̀̍̀͑̀͊͒̃͊͊̌̓̍̒ͅh̴̨͔̫̜̮̖̑͑̎͗͠i̵̧̡͍̣̳̻̥̙̬̲̪̪̦̮̻̩̦̭̫̣͙̦̱͍̼̒̊̆̽̋́̈͂̓́̄̆̂̓̉̇̉̃̃͒̌̓̾̆̒̚͜͝͝ͅs̵̢̢̧̜͚̝̯̮̼̟͍̗̞̘̙̍̋̈̿̇̾́̐ͅ ̷̨̨͕̳̝̰̭̞̱͎̖̞̤̘̯̪̮̺͇̙̃͜͠ͅͅi̶̧͖͓͎̫̲̗͇̳̞̬̞͔͖͉̅̌̿̏̐͝s̶̢̨̮̤̺̼̖̰͓̣̗̦̲͎̠̰͗̊̒̑͛̓̔͒̑̒̔̔͂̆̽̑̇̾̐̇͗́͊̀̀͊͑̓̕̕̚̕ ̵̛͓̯̦̯̞̩̀̓̈́̄͐͑͗̑͌̈́͂́̑̓̓͌̈́͗͑̈́̉̐̓͊̐͘̚͜͝ä̵̛̛͚̰̹̣́̒̈̈́̍͛̂̄͊̀͂̆̐̈́̓̔̎͑͗̈̋͂̓̃́́̽̽͘̕͠͝n̷̨̨̛̛̛͈̖͕̭̺̦̞̹̅̽̂̀̂̑͆̆̔̽̋̐̈́͒͑̓̉̀͑̈́̂̒̇̎̍͐̉͊͘͜͠͠ ̵̢͇͚͔̲̂́͊̅͒͑̕ȇ̷̢̡̛̩̦̫̝̙͚̱̲̳̗̠̫̜͓͙̘̹̩͖̹̪͔̙̘̹̻̟̜̰͚̄͊͐̓͂̂̂͌̈́̓͒̚͝x̷̨̬̄̂͂̈͐̾̋̐̕̚͠͝ͅả̵̧̨̰̣̳̖͕̞͙̗̳̝̬͎̯̫̘̫̝̼͍̩̜͎̭̹̘͈̮̎͐͛̓̽̋̏̈̌̈̊̓̅͐̈́̂̋̊̏̆̊̐̈́̽͛͌͛̀̅͘͜͝ͅḿ̸̡̡̛̛̞̜̮͈̤̮̬̦̯̪̪̜͇͇͈̬̞̞̯̟͕̠̻͈̬͔͚̋̎̉͌̏̈́̈̀͒̈́̀̈́̄̆̚͜ͅͅp̸̢̨̨̢̢̛̮̹͙̜̟̜͕̩͉͍̜̠̮̲̤̹̬̙̯͕͖̜͉͚̘͇͒̌́̉̾̓̀͊̎̔͛́̽́̾ͅl̵̢̠̱̲̗̯̹̼͔̳̘̫̯͑è̷̯̗̩̹͓̲͍͚̫͜ ̴̖̖͙̙͙͇̝͉̽̐͋͐̑͂̋̾̒̉̈́̋͊̎̈̉̉͒͂̆̕̚͝͝͝o̵̢͈͍͍̹͓͓͖̝̙̥͒͌͗́͋̌͛͊̐̈́̈́̍̌̈͋̏̅̆͛̈́͐̎̇͂̍̚͘͠͠͠ͅf̵̢̢̰̼̗̯̝̮͈̲͓͙̲̩̰͎̙͎̟͚̅́̍̑͒́̕͝͠ ̸̨̨̛̹̪̳̹͇̼̹̻̺̥͉̰̙͓̣͙̙̜̫̫̼̣̣̘͍͕͙̭͚̄̍̆̏̉̀̋̏̑̑͊͝ͅğ̷̤̬̜̼͕̇̈́͝ḽ̴̢̮̥̬̟͖̻̓̒̊͒̀͑̐̇͆̿̔́̓̚͠͝i̷̡̧͚͔̻̖̬̺̰̬̬̗̮̙̥̤͕̩̜̻̩̪̙̯̳̅̓̓̀̑̇͗̉̑̽̔͊̂̈́̑̓̀̄͑̀̓̓̋̈́̄̄́̊̕͘͝͝ͅt̸̨̝̺͉̥̗͇͍̤̦̂c̵̡͇̜̠͍͇͖̯͕͇̝͎̬͕͑̒͆͗̆͛̍̀͛͊̈́h̴͈̭͔͎̭͚̱̼̾͂ ̷̢͔͓̭̥̠͈͚͈͕͈̳̜͙̤̲̥̮̳̞̱̰̱̇̍̍̔͂̃̐͑̊̾͘͘͘͜͜t̶̡̧̧̯̺̖͖͎͉̦̫̯͇̠͖͉͉̮͎͕̫͍̯̖̘͖̱͔͉̹͎͙̔̈́̈͑̉̑̇̎̓̓̑͛̒̄̄̑͐̅̑͊̎̿̔̐̅́̄̿͒̕̚̚̕̚͜e̶̡̡̨̩̤͓͔̪͙̥̫͍̍̐̀̂͛͜ͅx̴̡̨͓͎̼̞͚̬̀̅̈́̓͒͊̑̾̒̈̅̄̈́̽̃̏̆̋͑͊͑̒̌̕̚͠t̸̛̛̹͔͎̻̜̫̰̪̟͉̩̩̹͆̅̔͛̋͐̆͛͋̀̾̒̌́́͌͝͝͝

Comment: It's called `Zalgo`, related qn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356977/117534

Comment: +1 Thanks! I wasn't even sure what terms to use in my search!

Comment: Np! Can you try and confirm whether the solution in the linked question works for you?

Comment: It does! Should I remove this question?

Comment: I would 'vote' to close it as a duplicate instead of deleting. See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2570/117534). I think 'glitch text' might be a good keyword for future users.